# extract part of word into a field from a long string using R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a single long string variable with 3 obs. I was trying to create a field prob to extract the specific string from the long string. the code and message is below.

data aa: "The probability of being a carrier is 0.0002422359 " " an BRCA1 carrier 0.0001061067 "
" an BRCA2 carrier 0.00013612 "

enter code here
aa$prob <- ifelse(grepl("The probability of being a carrier is", xx)==TRUE, word(aa, 8, 8), ifelse(grepl("BRCA", xx)==TRUE, word(aa, 5, 5), NA))

Warning message: In aa$prob <- ifelse(grepl("The probability of being a carrier is", : Coercing LHS to a list

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65987248/3358272) to one of your question (relatively identical) not work? It perfectly extracts the numbers from the fields, all you needed was to add `as.numeric`.

Comment: Hi r2evans, thank you for you instructions. it works. I got the 3 values out. but don't know what is the field name in data set after I run the code: Ssub <- aa[ grepl("(carrier is)", aa) | grepl("(carrier)", aa) ]
bb <- as.numeric(regmatches(Ssub, gregexpr("\\b[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*", Ssub)))

Comment: the console window shows: > bb
[1] 0.0002422359 0.0001061067 0.0001361200

Comment: for give me, I jump from SAS to R for a week. I have many concept problem

Comment: is bb a data frame name or variable name?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65987248/3358272), updated to reflect a `data.frame`.

```r
library(dplyr)

aa <- data.frame(aa = c("...", "...", "The probability of being a carrier is 0.0002422359 ", " an BRCA1 carrier 0.0001061067 ", " an BRCA2 carrier 0.00013612 ", "..."))

aa %>%
  mutate(prob = as.numeric(if_else(grepl("(probability|BRCA[12] carrier)", aa), 
                                   gsub("^.*?\\b([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\s*$", "\\1", aa), NA_character_)))
#                                                    aa         prob
# 1                                                 ...           NA
# 2                                                 ...           NA
# 3 The probability of being a carrier is 0.0002422359  0.0002422359
# 4                      an BRCA1 carrier 0.0001061067  0.0001061067
# 5                        an BRCA2 carrier 0.00013612  0.0001361200
# 6                                                 ...           NA
```

Regex walk-through:

- `^` and `$` are beginning and end of string, respective; `\\b` is a word-boundary; none of these "consume" any characters, they just mark beginnings and endings
- `.` means one character
- `?` means "zero or one", aka optional; `*` means "zero or more"; `+` means "one or more"; all refer to the previous character/class/group
- `\\s` is blank space, including spaces and tabs
- `[0-9]` is a class, meaning any character between 0 and 9; similarly, `[a-z]` is all lowercase letters, `[a-zA-Z]` are all letters, `[0-9A-F]` are hexadecimal digits, etc
- `(...)` is a saved group; it's not uncommon in a group to use `|` as an "or"; this group is used later in the `replacement=` part of `gsub` as numbered groups, so `\\1` recalls the first group from the pattern

So grouped and summarized:

```
  "^.*?\\b([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\s*$"
1         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2      ^^^
3   ^^^
4                           ^^^^
```

1. This is the "number" part, that allows for one or more digits, an optional decimal point, and zero or more digits. This is saved in group "1".
2. The word boundary guarantees that we include leading numbers (it's possible, depending on a few things, for `"12.345"` to be parsed as `"2.345"` without this.
3. Anything before the number-like string.
4. Some or no blank space after the number.

Grouped logically, in an organized way

Regex isn't unique to R, it's a parsing language that R (and most other programming languages) supports in one way or another.

Comment: This is a great help. I'm a beginner for R. could you please explain what that mean of "^.*?\\b([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\s*$", "\\1", in gsub part? thank you

Comment: Sorry, I only see "Active", "Oldest" and "Vote" button available beside the Answer. I did not see accept button. I checked the link as well, but still can not find it. Sorry about it. I really want to accept it.

Comment: To the *left* of that, you should see an up/down voter, a number (currently 0), and below that you should have a gray checkmark (since you're the original poster). Clicking on that arrow should accept it.

Comment: just did it. it say "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." will check it 15' later Thank you for your help!!!